# I must be misunderstanding Celluloid

Tags: ruby

I currently have a script written in Ruby that scans a range of IP addresses and tries to connect to them. It's extremely slow at the moment. It takes up to 300 seconds to scan 254 hosts on the network, and that's obviously not very practical. What I'm trying to do is give the script some concurrency in hopes of speeding up the script. So far this is what I have:

```
require 'socket'
require 'celluloid'

$res_arr = []


class Ranger
include Celluloid

def initialize(host)
    @host = host
    @timeout = 1
end


def ip_range(host)
    host =~ /(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}[xX*]{1,3}/
end


def ctrl(host)
    begin

        if ip_range(host)
            strIP = host.gsub(/[xX*]/, '')

            (1..254).each do |oct|
                $res_arr << strIP+oct.to_s
            end
        else
            puts "Invalid host!"
        end

    rescue
        puts "onnection terminated."
    end
end

def connect
    addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(@host, nil)
    sock = Socket.new(Socket.const_get(addr[0][0]), Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)


    begin
        sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(22, addr[0][3]))

    rescue Errno::EINPROGRESS
        resp = IO.select(nil, [sock], nil, @timeout.to_i)

        if resp.nil?
            $res_arr << "#{@host} Firewalled!"
        end

        begin
            if sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(22, addr[0][3]))
                $res_arr << "#{@host}Connected!"
            end

        rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
            $res_arr << "#{@host} Refused!"

        rescue
            false
        end
    end
    sock
end


def output(contents)
    puts contents.value
end


end # Ranger

main = Ranger.new(ARGV[0])
main.ctrl(ARGV[0])

$res_arr.each do |ip|
    scan = Ranger.new(ip)
    scnftr = scan.future :connect
    scan.output(scnftr)
end
```

The script works, but it takes just as long as before I included Celluloid at all. Am I misunderstanding how Celluloid works and what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that each iteration of your loop starts a future, then immediately waits for it to return a value. What you want instead is start all futures, then wait for all futures to finish in two separate steps:

```
futures = $res_arr.map do |ip|
  scan = Ranger.new(ip)
  scan.future :connect
end

# now that all futures are running, we can start
# waiting for the first one to finish

futures.each do |future|
  puts future.value
end
```

Here's another example from the celluloid source: https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/blob/master/examples/simple_pmap.rb

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confused, I don't see in your code where scnftr is defined. Also the second block throws and error about scan being undefined.

Comment: Sorry for that. The first issue was a typo, it must be `future` instead of `scnftr` in the second block. The second issue is that `scan` is not defined. However I think you can throw the `output` method away, it has nothing to do in the class! It does not use the instance in any way. Instead, just write `puts future.value` directly. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. It's very very close to working. The script is MUCH faster now, which was the whole point of this thread. The only problem is the format of the output. My script accurately outputs each host and whether it's open, closed, or filtered. The trouble is that it output this all out of order - the open hosts are shown first, instead of being in order of IP. Also, mixed in with the appropriate output is a bunch of these: #<Socket:0x000000017c6540>. How do I get rid of these?